# j-interop does not work to monitor Win7 via WMI

Tags: java, wmi, jacob, opennms, j-interop

I used j-interop to monitor Windows system via WMI in Java. It does work for monitoring remote WinXP from both Windows and Linux client. But it does not work to remotely monitor Windows7 from both Windows and Linux client.
I also checked with OpenNMS, it also used j-interop and does not work for Win7 too.
My questions are:

1. Is there any workaround to let j-interop work for monitoring
   Windows7?
2. Is there any other java library works cross-platform without the Windows 7 issue?I have tested JACOB, it does work for Windows7, but it is notcross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch 'regedit.exe' as 'Administrator'

   1. Find the following registry key: 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}'
   2. Right click and select 'Permissions'
   3. Click the 'Advanced' button.
   4. Select the tab labeled 'Owner'
   5. Add the user you want to allow to connect to the owners list
   6. Click the 'Ok' button.
   7. Now highlight the user and grant Full Control
   8. Click 'Ok'

Retrieved from "http://www.opennms.org/wiki/WmiConfiguration";

I have tested that it did work for Win7